# include an included view with blade and Laravel 4

Tags: include, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I want to use a partial view with content from another partial view, something like this:

```
@include('view1', array('content' => @include('view2')))
```

Unfortunately the `view2`is rendered as expected but `view1`is not, and just outputs `@include`in plain text.

The 2 views are not related at all therefore I believe I cannot use `@yield` (as this will mean a view will have to extend another).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the inclusion of both views aren't dynamic, when returning the master view (the one that contains the include), you can nest view2

```
return View::make('master')->nest('content', 'view2');
```

Then in the view

```
@include('view1', array('content' => $content))
```

That or you could just include view2 within view1, is there a specific reason that this needs to be in the master view?

Comment: I've looked around with your solution and it seems to be the good one but for some reasons the 2 variables I pass to `view2`in parameters both returns `1` (but the nested `$content` variable outputs fine in the master).